# Packets in bridge get up to the user space without being redirected there

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge

I set up a bridge interface (br0) on PC-A (Linux Ubunutu 14.04)

In addition I created an application with a TCP Listener on port 80 in the user-space on PC-A

As what I understood from the documentation of Netfilter and bridge-utils is that the bridge suppose to route the packets through the kernel without bubble it up into the user space but when I connect a wired (p2p) PC-B to the bridge pc (PC-A) and surf to a HTTP web I can see the packets are being received in the listener which means that the packets got into the user-space.

I have to say that there are no ebtables rules in any chain that tells packet to redirect up to the user-space.

The strangest thing here is that I have the same configuration in another location and the packets don't get up there to the user-space unless I add a broute rule (which is the expected behavior I guess)

Any change anyone knows what can cause the strange behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "an application with a TCP listener on port 80"? Do you just mean that a regular TCP socket bound to port 80 on which you called `listen`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes @David Schwartz. I meant a TCP socket that bound  to the br0 interface's IP and port 80

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the answer, but there is limit of the comment lenght, so I have written this text as answer.

To redirect the switched frames to local port you can done the next steps:
Set the sysctl variable `bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1` (kernel module `br_netfilter` should be loaded). Add the redirecting rule for switched packets. Something like this:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \
  -m physdev --physdev-is-in br0 \
  -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80`

Related readings:

1. [ip-sysctl documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/davem/net.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)
2. `iptables -m <match-name> --help` - short help of match usage
3. `iptables -j <TARGET-NAME> --help` - short help of target usage

To troubleshoot your issue you can done:

1. Check your iptables and ebtables rulesets.
2. Dump the traffic with tcpdump/wireshark and check the destination addresses (mac and ip) of this packets (if userspace app receive this packets, then packets are destinated to your host PC-A).

Answer (score 1):

Pointing an IP on the bridge Means the  the  packets are destined for the Bridges MAC address and so the normal Local delivery packet  receiving process is invoked.

The two different paths look a bit like this.
Let's say we have  eth1 and eth2 connected via br1

1) packet arrives on eth1 Destined for an non-local MAC,  packet is forward by kernel through the bridge and out to eth2. No  user-space   Or IP layer processing occurred. (Unless a specific netfilter rule is used to intercept it - see other answer)

2) packet arrives on eth1 destined for the MAC of the bridge. Here the packet doesn't leave the bridge but instead is received by the  IP stack as an  normal inbound packet on br1.  This packet is then processed and then the  data is forwarded to the process listening on port 80 on the br1 interface.

The "bubbling " to user space is enabled by the listening port. It's not really related to interface type.

putting an IP on a bridge is pretty usefully if you want to bridge 2 interfaces  and communicate to hosts on both sides of the bridge.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Why is this behaviour an issue?